# Is there any way get tweets timeline from a nodejs script using the oficial twitter-api-sdk?

Tags: node.js, typescript, twitter, twitter-api-v2

This sdk only supports App-only Bearer Token and OAuth 2.0. Using the bearer token is not possible to read timelines, and OAuth 2.0 requires a callback URL (and because this is a node.js script, we don't have one).

Using bearer token I get this response:

```
error: {
  title: 'Unsupported Authentication',
  detail: 'Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 2.0 User Context, OAuth 1.0a User Context].',
  type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication',
  status: 403
}
```

The only way to do it from a node.js script is using OAuth 1.0a User Context authentication method but it seems that is not supported by the SDK. Weird!

I know there are another no oficial npm packages but they are no longer maintained by their owners since the new policies that twitter has applied.

I know I can use the HTTP API they provide, but maybe there is another way.